# Check if Variable has changed in Obj C

Tags: objective-c

How do you repeatedly check whether a variable has changed?

Currently I'm using a hook class from a game engine to access the score like so:

```
 float score = ScoreController::scores().points.current();
```

The function is only called once from the AppDelegate, so I need a method to continuously check if the score then changes after I find out what it is, but I'm unsure how to approach this?

I'm thinking the logic would be:

```
 //store current score (as above)
     //if score increases (not sure how to check)
          //do something
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What causes the score to increase?  Can whatever that is send a notification or execute a callback to inform you of the change?

Comment: Unfortunately due to the nature of the game engine, the only variable you can check is the current `points` as shown above.

Comment: So, nothing in your code causes the current points to change?  Sounds odd...but, OK.

Comment: I'm using a hook class to access the Scores created in the `ScoreController`, and the only variable made available by the Game Engine is the `points.current`. I can not access the Game Engine code. Otherwise I wouldn't need to use their hook class.

Comment: You can use [gcd as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14582980/102315) to check the points in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NSTimer`.

```c
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 1; //How frequently to check for the score change.
CGFloat score = ScoreController::scores().points.current();
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer *timer) {
     CGFloat newScore = ScoreController::scores().points.current();

    if (score != newScore) {
        //Score changed. Call a delegate or something.
    }
}];
```